# Can I pump my MTB tire to max (55 psi / 380 kPa) without the tube inside bursting?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, commuter, innertube, tire-pressure

I have a e-mountain bike and I use to commute to uni every day. I have heard that higher tire pressures give you a bit more speed. My tires say I can pump to 55 psi (380 kPa) but I don't know if my tube can handle the same pressure. Don't want to buy a new tube. I currently have them at 40 psi (280 kPa). Will 47 to 50 psi (320–380 kPa) burst my tubes?

Comment: I happen to have just bought a tube so I have the packaging and the tube on hand to examine. Mine happens to be a Continental tube for 26x1.75-2.5. There is no mention of maximum pressure on the packaging or the tube itself. The pressure limit is set by the tire, so if the sidewall of the tire says max 55 psi, then go with that.

Comment: I would avoid over-inflation.  It's unlikely to help and will make your ride less comfortable.  You will also be more likely to get a flat if you hit a pothole or curb.  Using smoother or even thinner tires is a better option.  There are styles that have a smooth center line and knobby sides if you want to have a fair off-road capability.

Comment: Shouldn't snakebite flats be caused by too-low pressure, not too-high?

Comment: @VladimirF I think both are an issue.  My recent experience is with road bikes and I've had a lot fewer flats since I stopped maxing out the pressure.  But we are talking 120 PSI versus 55 so it may not apply here.

Comment: But certainly with my gravel bike I try to keep the pressure as low as possible. It is not slow and it is much better experience in any kind of terrain, so I can actually ride faster. I would not recommend to go for high pressure on a mountain bike, I think bikers also try to go pretty low and use mostly tubeless tyres for that.

Comment: On tarmac the harder, the better.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Not true, unless the tarmac is exceptionally smooth: see my answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I looked at a few charts online, and they all agree with my experience, which is admittedly limited to normal consumer tyres, like the one in the question. (With respect to the underlying physics: The energy expended to climb a bump is mostly recovered when going down on the other side. The recovery rate increases with pressure because less deformation happens. (This considers only the deformation of the tyre; if the ground is soft and deforms, softer tyres become energetically advantageous because some of the tyre deformation is recovered as well, as opposed to ground def. .)

Comment: @DavidRicherby And besides, regular tarmac *is* pretty smooth relative to tyre size. Unless the road is damaged there should be no significant up and down from bumps; If I venture a guess, the small imperfections and gravel on city roads (the OP is riding to university) probably vanish mostly in the rubber and tyre deformation. The situation would be different on cobblestone, and more different on unpaved roads.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider "Unless the road is damaged" Maybe roads are better where you are. In the UK, that's a bit like saying "Unless the sun rises in the east."

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider *The energy expended to climb a bump is mostly recovered when going down on the other side.* Except for all the energy lost to making the road buzz sounds, and all the energy lost into vibrating your hands and bottom, neither of which are elastic springs.  In your experience, did you actually **measure** your speed vs power over different surfaces? Way too many rolling resistance charts come from measuring resistance on a perfectly smooth surface.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm always eager to learn new things (not being sarcastic here), but for now I see personal experience, scientific evidence and reasonable theory all align (the losses you mention notwithstanding). Did *you* measure? Do you know of more carefully produced charts?

Comment: In short - your tube hold the air from leaking while the tyre holds the pressure.

Comment: I used to ride a MTB to work daily and after a few months changed to a kevilar road tire (only cost like £20 on Amazon) and it could support a higher psi and because it was rounder, made the cycle so much faster and easier.

Comment: weird, my bike's maximum psi is 65

Comment: @AndrewHenle Funny, today I stumbled over research and charts linked to in [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/59779/how-much-stiffer-are-23c-tires-over-28c) which you may have had in mind. They may explain our different views. Essentially, about 10 years ago, Tom Anhalt performed experiments he wrote about [here](https://www.slowtwitch.com/Tech/What_s_in_a_tube__1034.html). They showed that at about 100PSI/6.8 bar rolling resistance increases quite dramatically on real world surfaces through the mechanism you describe.

Comment: @DavidRicherby (in addition to addressing Andrew ;-) ) (ctd.) A good write-up building on Anhalt's work is [here](https://silca.cc/blogs/journal/part-4a-rolling-resistance-the-history-and-previous-works). The relatively high pressures needed to cross the minimum rolling resistance spot on tarmac may be the reason for my personal experience that inflating more never hurts. Another good general information source is [this Schwalbe technical paper.](https://www.schwalbe.com/en/catalogesflyer.html?file=files/schwalbe/userupload/PDF/Kataloge/2015/TechInfo-2015_GB.pdf)

Comment: @LamMunnJuan It's not weird at all: different tyres and rims are rated for different pressures. Typically, wider tyres are rated for lower pressures so, while a 25mm road tyre might max out at 120psi, a thirty-something hybrid tyre might only go up to 80psi and the asker's MTB tyres only 55psi.

Answer (score 18):

It can't burst the tube, because the tube is completely surrounded by the tyre and rim.

Bear in mind, though, that higher pressures don't automatically mean a faster ride. There are two competing factors: a soft tyre is constantly losing energy due to being squashed flat against the road, but a hard tyre loses energy because any bumps you go over have to lift the whole bike, instead of just deforming the tyre.  I don't ride mountain bikes so I don't know where that trade-off starts to bite.

On an e-bike, I'm not sure this will make much difference, though: it just means that the assist motor will have to work less hard at any given speed.

Comment: You could make it clearer that the tube does not take any significant part of the pressure; the tyre does it alone. One can see how little pressure a tube can hold by pumping one up, without the tyre. It's a better balloon.

Comment: Small note for e-bikes. eMTB are almost always Class 1, for which the motor cuts out at 20 MPH. If you increase the outer diameter of the tire, the motor will assist you up to a higher actual speed, as you're moving faster for a given rate of tire rotation. IF inflating a tire to a higher pressure increases the outer diameter, then you do effectively have a higher motor assisted top speed.

Comment: @Adonalsium OK but any such difference is going to be negligible: a 1% increase in tyre outer diameter will give a 1% increase in speed.

Comment: What kind of bumps are you going over that only have an uphill side?

Comment: @PhilFrost Nothing is 100% efficient, so the energy you lost on the uphill side won't be fully restored to you on the downhill.

Comment: Better than rolling resistance, which converts energy to heat which isn't recovered at all. Lower pressure makes a larger contact patch, reducing sheer forces on the soil which means more "grip". But it certainly doesn't make the bike roll more efficiently.

Comment: In my experience the upper end of a MTB tyre pressure range is still soft enough to absorb most bumps as well as most of the rest of the range.  The biggest difference is seen when moving onto the road, where the rolling resistance is greatly lowered.  If doing a lot of road cycling, I can recommend the tyres with a solid central rim, as when hard, this lifts most of the tyre off the road, removing most of the resistance.  It still performs on soft ground too.

Comment: @Phil Frost it depends very much on properties of the tyre, such as sidewall stiffness. So called suspension losses may contribute considerably to overall rolling resistance. Thus doesn't even take increased fatigue into account. The rider is the main inelastic member. The jolts that dissipate energy in their body also have to be compensated by muscular action. Eccentric contraction doesn't generate biochemically useful energy.

Comment: Here are a couple of articles that discuss this.  The upshot for me is not that lower is always better but that somewhere in the middle between min and max pressure is preferable.  https://janheine.wordpress.com/2019/01/03/myth-16-higher-tire-pressure-is-faster/ https://www.velonews.com/2014/12/bikes-and-tech/resistance-futile-tire-pressure-width-affect-rolling-resistance_355085

Comment: @JimmyJames The first link is [selling wide tires](https://www.renehersecycles.com/). The 2nd link concludes higher pressure has lower rolling resistance: "I had expected the wider tires to have lower rolling resistance than the narrower ones. I had also expected the rolling resistance to be less at lower pressure. While at first glance the former seems to be in doubt, a closer look reveals that that assumption is probably sound. The latter was proven not to be true, however." And in both cases, the "low" pressure tested is much higher than the 55 psi in the question. So I remain skeptical.

Comment: @PhilFrost I posted these two because they don't say exactly the same thing but if you look at the tests, they actually align pretty well. I didn't look closely enough at the question initially, the OP could probably inflate more and get better road results.

Comment: @PhilFrost First article goes, there are two conclusions: "On really rough surfaces, higher pressures roll slower. Wider tires roll faster on rough surfaces because they can handle lower pressures." and "If you want to go fast, you need supple tires. That is all. Pumping them up harder won’t make you faster. On rough surfaces, it actually makes you slower." There's a good charts starting about 1/3 down the page labelled: "Summary: On real roads, even smooth ones, higher pressures don’t roll faster."  You can see a tire at 35PSI and 55PSI with almost identical performance and so on.

Comment: @PhilFrost For the second article, I noticed that but it's a little confusing because when you get into the actual details, it says things like: "On the road, there will be a point with every surface where, above a certain pressure, rolling resistance will increase." and "Interestingly, the tires with the highest rolling resistance, the two Fortés, have almost no difference in rolling resistance at 84 psi versus 112 psi." The issue is nuanced but I think the point that higher pressure isn't always faster bears out.  I've found it to be the case personally.

Comment: @PhilFrost In that case look at a four-years later article concentrating on harsher surfaces https://www.velonews.com/2018/06/from-the-mag/optimal-tire-pressure-gravel_468329 The lowest rolling resistance for them was 30 PSI on a 35 mm tyre. The OPs MTB tyre must be much larger.

Answer (score 2):

The tensile forces are borne by the tire, not the tube. So go ahead and pump it up to the maximum pressure on the tire if you're riding mostly on roads. I think you'll find the bike rolls significantly easier.

David Richerby argues a tire too hard will lead to a less efficient ride. JimmyJames gives [two](https://janheine.wordpress.com/2019/01/03/myth-16-higher-tire-pressure-is-faster/) [examples](https://www.velonews.com/2014/12/bikes-and-tech/resistance-futile-tire-pressure-width-affect-rolling-resistance_355085) of testing lower pressures in road tires. Apparently there is a significant "lower is faster" camp of roadies. Their argument isn't applicable to your situation, in fact the data suggest 55 psi is what you want. A higher pressure would probably be better, if the tire could handle it.

Here's a graph from [the first example](https://janheine.wordpress.com/2019/01/03/myth-16-higher-tire-pressure-is-faster/):

[image]

This is the time taken to roll down a test hill: less is better. For the two clinchers tested (your tires are almost certainly clinchers), in neither case did they find a pressure that was "too high". For the tubulars, they did find a higher pressure that was slower, but look at the pressures involved: the lowest pressure tested was *85 psi!* Not to mention of course your tires aren't tubulars, you aren't on a road bike, and you probably aren't riding as fast and you probably don't have high-end tires. Also note the potentially misleading axis which starts at 24: this makes the differences between tests look much more significant than it really is. Also note the author of this article [is selling something](https://www.renehersecycles.com/).

The data from [the second example](https://www.velonews.com/2014/12/bikes-and-tech/resistance-futile-tire-pressure-width-affect-rolling-resistance_355085):

[image]

This shows the power required to sustain 40 kph. Lower is better. Note in *every case*, higher pressure was better. In some cases the margin was very small. And again note the pressures tested: the "low" pressure is too high for your tires: 84 psi.

Comment: *Apparently there is a significant "lower is faster" camp of roadies. Their argument isn't applicable to your situation* I'm glad someone did notice that a 2"+ (50+ mm) MTB tire designed to handle at least some off-road use at 55 psi isn't really comparable to a 1"/25mm or less road tire at 120 psi.

Comment: The magazine in the second example has a followup https://www.velonews.com/2018/06/from-the-mag/optimal-tire-pressure-gravel_468329 And that one shows a *very* different story. For a 35mm tyre they found 30PSI to be the fastest on a gravel road.

Comment: @VladimirF When the OP is riding _gravel roads_ on a _road frame_ and a _high quality 35 mm tire_, I'll change my recommendation. But since he's _on roads_ with a _mountain bike_ and what's likely a _low quality, much wider_ tire, I maintain the tires will explode well before they are "too hard".

Answer (score 1):

I know from my own experience (several decades of riding bicycles of various sorts) that harder tyres roll quicker and resist puncturing more (particularly on the road), but softer tyres grip better (particularly offroad). Only your own experience will find you the best compromise between the two for your riding style. 
The one thing I found could force a tyre off the rim (and therefore explode the tube - with a very load BANG!) was a flat spot on the rim, but I did pump the tyre up to 115 PSI. The tube was in no way to blame. A round rim would prevent this from happening at recomended pressures.